# jQuery - deferring ajax function return on success only?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, jquery-deferred

I've got some code set up, and I'd like to get a very simple API going for ajax requests.

So, what I'd like to do is simply do is use deferred somehow to return success.

```
var factory = function(dataParams) {
    return $.ajax({
        type       : "POST",
        dataType   : "json",
        url        : "http://example.com/whatever",
        data       : dataParams,
        beforeSend : function(jqXHR, settings){/*... something here ...*/},
        error      : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){/*... something here ...*/},
        complete   : function(jqXHR, textStatus) {/*... something here ...*/}
});
```

Which would get called by something such as

```
var dataTools = {
    "foo" : function(){
        factory({"One": 1}).success(function(jqXHR){
            //Do something to jqXHR
            //Return something to the "upper most" calling... how?
        })
    }
    "bar" : function(){
        factory({"Two": 2}).success(function(jqXHR){
            //Return jqXHR to the "upper most" calling... how?
        })
    }
};
```

Such that I could use it in this way:

```
$.each(dataTools.foo(), function(k,v){
    console.log(v);
});
```

Basically, the object `dataTools.foo` returns a value from success, or, should return an empty set in the vent of a failure, or something that skips that code branch.

I've attempted using `$.when().then()`, but I can't seem to figure out how to fit that into something like I've described here.

Comment: Did you mean to write `var dataTools = {` ?

Comment: What is the aim of you "deferring" the success function?  are you trying to build a re-usable request object?

Comment: @Derek Adair, yes. I'd like to use this as a means to get some data, and return everything when it's all done, rather than use a callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is asynchronous.

You cannot use a `$.each` on an asynchronous function.

You cannot have a function calling a function calling ajax then expect to use `$.when` and the related functions.

You need to do something like is said in the **[doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)**

---

Try something like this:

```
var dataTools = {
    "foo" : function(){
        $.when(factory({"One": 1})).done(function(a1, a2){
            var jqXHR = a1[2]; /* arguments are [ "success", statusText, jqXHR ] */
        });
    }
    "bar" : function(){
        $.when(factory({"Two": 2})).done(function(a1, a2){
            var jqXHR = a1[2]; /* arguments are [ "success", statusText, jqXHR ] */
        });
    }
};
```